# How can I change IntelliJ "Class to Import" order?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

**Code - before**:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
...
Assert.assertEquals(a,b);
Assert.assertEquals(c,d);
```

**Steps**:

1. I remove the first `Assert.`:

   ```
   assertEquals(a,b);
   Assert.assertEquals(c,d);
   ```

   Now the first `assertEquals` is red.
2. Now I click on the first `assertEquals` and I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   [image]
3. I select "Static import method..." and I see the following popup:
   [image]

   If I click on the last line (the blue line) all lines containing `Assert.assertEquals...` become `assertEquals...`.

**Code - after**:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
...
assertEquals(a,b);
assertEquals(c,d);
```

**Questions**

Is it possible to change the order in the "Class to Import" window? I always want to see the blue line (`org.junit`) in the first place.

Or is it possible to remove the other options? For every `assert` I want to use `org.junit.Assert`.

**Details:**

- Windows 7
- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to File -> Settings... (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)  -> *Editor* -> *General* -> *Auto Import* and add packages to *Exclude from Import and Completion* that you don't want to see.

[image]

Comment: Nice. I see that it can be done from step 3 (right arrow) too. Thanks!